# cant iterate through list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having an issue with iterating through a list to add items to a list of dictionaries.I believe my issue is in the list_to_dictionary function. "for muns in mun" returns "Mun" which is a item in the list. It only iterates through the list once because its saying the only item in the list is "Mun". i need to create a dictionary for each event. Not sure what the problem is, thanks.

```
#iterates though lists and puts value at location "count"
#into a dictionary and loops until there are no more events
def list_to_dictionary():
    count = 0
    for muns in mun:
        print muns
        event = {'Agency ': agency[count], 'Time ': time[count], 'Units ': units[count], 'Description ': description[count], 'Street ': street[count], 'Cross Streets ': crossStreets[count], 'Municipality ': mun[count]}
        count += 1
        return event

create_list(allTable)
```

Comment: elif counter is 7:
                mun.extend([row.text])
                counter = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to add an item to a list, you should use append, not extend.  E.g. `mun.append(row.text)` instead of `mun.extend([row.text])`

Second, in your list_to_dictionary function, you are returning in the first iteration of the loop, so of course it won't loop through the entire list. I'm assuming you want to return a list of events, not the first event.

Third, you should simplify the logic. Rather than creating a bunch of lists and then using their indices to create dictionaries afterward, why not just create a dictionary in the first loop for each event and create a list of events.

```
    events = []
    event = {}
    counter = 1
    for row in allTable.findAll('td'):
        if counter is not 8:
            if counter is 1:
                event['agency'] = row.text
                counter += 1
            elif counter is 2:
                event['time'] = row.text
                counter += 1
```

...

```
            elif counter is 7:
                event['mun'] = row.text
                events.append(event)
                event = {}
                counter = 1
```

Comment: i like this, but I'm having another issue after implementing it. 
for e in events:
    print e

returns the same dictionary again and again.

Comment: Sorry just made an edit - have to reset your event variable when your counter reaches 7

Answer (score 3):

```
return event
```

is inside your loop, so the loop stops at the first iteration.

Your probably want to add event to a list of dictionary and return the list *after* the loop

```
def list_to_dictionary():
    count = 0
    events = []
    for muns in mun:
        print muns
        event = {'Agency ': agency[count], 'Time ': time[count], 'Units ': units[count], 'Description ': description[count], 'Street ': street[count], 'Cross Streets ': crossStreets[count], 'Municipality ': mun[count]}
        events.append(event)
        count += 1
    return events
```